# Getting set timeout value on authenticated endpoint

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting a numeric value for the seconds I need to set the set timeout interval. This interval will have multiple requests inside. I can't grab the value for the endpoint if there isn't a token bearing header. Which brings me to my problem. If I get a 401 error, the function stops entirely. How would I have the function keep going if it's a 401. I don't think setting a default interval would work because you would just be wrapping an interval in an interval. Any thoughts? Thanks. This is ionic 2+, basically angular 2+

app.component.ts

```
constructor(){
this.firstInterval()
}

firstInterval(){
    this.service.getSeconds().subscribe(result => {
      result.secondsbetween
      this.getGPSInterval(result.secondsbetween, 60000)
    })
  }    

  getGPSInterval(firstTime, secondTime){

   if(firstTime > 0){ 
    setInterval(() => {
        this.endpoint()
  },parseInt(firstTime + '000') )
    }
    else{
      setInterval(() => {

             this.endpoint()

       },secondTime)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `finally` operator which will still be fired even error happened. Mention that you will still need a default interval in order that `this.service.getSeconds()` fails.

```
defaultInterval = 1000;    // your real default interval value
realInterval = null;
this.service.getSeconds().finally(() => {             // finally operator
  this.getGPSInterval(this.defaultInterval, 60000);   // defaultInterval: error => 1000, success =>  real interval value from result.secondsbetween
}).subscribe(result => {
  this.defaultInterval = result.secondsbetween;       // replace with real interval value from result.secondsbetween
})
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8nC0nzo1pmXQQTeXJxMY?p=preview)**.

Comment: Would it be possible that once the endpoint is authorized, the default interval is replaced with the real interval? As it stands it stays with what if else returns initially. I'm guessing I would have to add a third interval around that? Or it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm you can replace the default interval with the real interval

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm sorry for late response, see me updated answer.

Comment: Appreciate you replying! and unfortunately that option does not work. If It's unauthenticated initially and then I authenticate, I'm still getting the defaultinterval value for the interval.

Comment: Same result unfortunately :(

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm can you try reproduce your problem with the demo I provided?